# How to enable Javascript in R/`rvest` browser?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to scrape a website using `R` and `rvest`, but the HTML that I'm getting does not match the HTML structure of the webpage in my brower. Instead, I am getting a div that says "JavaScript is not enabled in your browser."

My goal is to get a login page so I can input some login information.

This is the code that gives me the output described:

```
url <- "google.com"
login <- rvest::read_html(url)
login %>% rvest::html_elements("body div div h1")

#> {xml_nodeset (2)}
#> [1] <h1>JavaScript is not enabled in your browser.</h1>
#> [2] <h1>JavaScript is not enabled in your browser.</h1>
```

If the site was loading correctly, the form would be inside this div:

```
url <- "google.com"
login <- rvest::read_html(url)
form <- login %>% rvest::html_elements("body div")
form[6]

#> {xml_nodeset (1)}
#> [1] <div data-js="login-form">\n        \n    </div>
```

If it's relevant, I'm using `rvest_1.0.3` and this is my system info:

```
R.version
#>                _                                
#> platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32               
#> arch           x86_64                           
#> os             mingw32                          
#> crt            ucrt                             
#> system         x86_64, mingw32                  
#> status                                          
#> major          4                                
#> minor          2.2                              
#> year           2022                             
#> month          10                               
#> day            31                               
#> svn rev        83211                            
#> language       R                                
#> version.string R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt)
#> nickname       Innocent and Trusting
```

Comment: `rvest` requests an html page from the server and that's what you are seeing in R. In your browser, the software takes the Javascript code on the page and processes it, often using it to generate further calls to the server to fetch data. `rvest` can't do this directly, though it is often possible to find what further http calls the code on the page makes, by using the developer tools in Chrome. This then allows you to recreate the request in `rvest`. If you want to scrape a full dynamic website without doing this, you need to use something like RSelenium to automate the browser.

Comment: Okay this is a super helpful explanation -- thanks @AllanCameron I'll try to find the http request or use `RSelenium`

Comment: It will probably be less than ideal experience, but *"checking out chromote branch of rvest"* would  kind of answer the question in title as this is where rvest integration with Chrome engine takes place. Though it's still in relatively early stage of development. https://github.com/tidyverse/rvest/blob/chromote/R/live.R